# Tracking c/c++ data structure sizes

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to find a tool that can show me information about all the data structures in a program.  I want to know when certain data structures were accessed and how their sizes changed throughout the course of the program.  For example I want the tool to know that all the nodes in a linked list belong to one single data structure.  Does a tool like this exist?  I couldn't seem to find one through googling.  Thanks

Comment: why are you worried about the size changing? Structures do change when data gets shovelled in, moved around. Difficult to measure as inputs/outputs change quite fast. Clarify your reasoning as to **why** you need it? More often if not, that is an indication of not fully understanding the code or runtime.

Comment: ... a debugger? o.O `gdb` is capable of providing a "high level interface" to structures in memory and you can set watch points on memory addresses.

Comment: _a tool that can show me information about all the data structures in a program... (access, times, sizes, etc.)_  You will have to write the tool that will do this.

Answer (score 0):

Some Toolchain, for example, Xcode's Toolchain, provides debugging features, which allows you to keep track of the memory use, CPU times and network using. The tracking data structure in memory could be achieved if you set breakpoint in the program. Without breakpoint, it's not likely to track the change of data structure since the CPU usually runs pretty fast. What you need is a good IDE with debugging, profiling ...

Comment: Debugging and profiling are toolchain features, not IDE features.

Comment: My bad. I should know that. Debugging is a very annoying process.

Answer (score 0):

My first question is: what's your compiler? One person mentioned gdb as a useful tool, but that's only the case if you're using gcc/g++. Xcode has its own compiler/debugger. MicroSoft has its own as well.

Ultimately, this is about knowing how to use the debugger for your compiler. Also, realize that using the debugger for your compiler properly can be just as daunting a task as learning how to use your compiler.

There are also profilers available, but again, it will depend somewhat on your compiler as to which ones are available for you. Your keywords for googling will be "C++", "debugger", and "profiler", ideally along with the name of your compiler.

Be aware, as well, that your compiler *may* impact the statistics when your program runs against the same data.